# How to use `map()` with kwargs argument

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

The `map` function is good way to parallelly compute function values. When the function has keyword parameters, how to use the map? For example:

```
def func(a, b=0, c=0):

    print a, b, c
```

Sometimes, kwargs is convenient to pass parameters to function, ignoring the argument sequence to call. Can map function can be used like this?

```
map(func, range(3), c=[1, 3, 5])
```

However, it would be TypeError.

```
TypeError: map() takes no keyword arguments
```

Is there any simple way to continue use `map()` with keyword arguments?

Comment: You need to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to create a single-argument callable with those keyword arguments preset.

Comment: Maybe lambda expression would be useful here.
map(lamda x: func(x, c=[1, 3, 5]), range(3))